# How to wait for suspend function to be completed before executing other code in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I'm wondering if I can wait until a suspend function has completed before executing other code? `loadParticlesWithoutSetCall`, which I call inside of `setParticlePicking`, has a suspend function. I do not want anything else in `setParticlePicking` to be called until the suspend function has finished. Please let me know.

```
fun setParticlePicking(particlePicking: ParticlePicking) {
    loadParticlesWithoutSetCall()

    manualParticleMarkers?.forEach {
        imageContainerElem.remove(it)
    }
    currentParticlePicking = particlePicking
    manualParticleMarkers = (particlePicking.pickings [imageID]?.map {
        val marker = ManualParticleMarker(it.x, it.y, image = imageElem, trueHeight = particlesDat!!.imageHeight, trueWidth = particlesDat!!.imageWidth, h = particlesDat!!.h(0), w = particlesDat!!.w(0), parentElem = this@ParticlesImage.imageContainerElem)
        imageContainerElem.add(marker)
        marker
    }?: mutableListOf()) as MutableList<ManualParticleMarker>
    placeMarkers()
}



fun loadParticlesWithoutSetCall() {
    AppScope.launch {
        // clear everything
        particlesElem.removeAll()


        // load the particles
        val loadingElem = particlesElem.loading("Fetching particles ...")
        val particles: ParticlesData? = try {
            loader()
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            errorMessage(t)
            null
        } finally {
            particlesElem.remove(loadingElem)
            toWait = true
        }

        particlesDat = particles
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark both functions suspending functions by adding the `suspend` modifier before `fun`. Then move the `AppScope.launch {}` call to wrap the call to `setParticlePicking`, wherever it is (you did not include in the sample).

It should look something like this:

```kotlin
AppScope.launch {
    setParticlePicking(particlePicking)
}
```

Since you will have removed the `AppScope.launch {}` call from `loadParticlesWithoutSetCall`, `setParticlePicking` will wait for its code to complete before moving on with the rest of the code, because suspending functions are [sequential by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#sequential-by-default).

Comment: What is `AppScope`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I assumed `AppScope` was an instance of `CoroutineScope`, meant as a placeholder. You can get a coroutine scope from different places, depending on the framework and platform that you are using. The easiest method is to use `runBlocking {}` on JVM.